# How to add bootstrap 4 nav item to a class active using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, jekyll

I have a jekyll site, to this I want to add class `active` bootstrap 4 class dynamically using javascript. I used below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get current URL path and assign 'active' class
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    $('.navbar-nav > li > a[href="'+pathname+'"]').addClass('active');
})
```

code is in `footer.js` loaded in source.
But it only working for home page [here](https://govtexam.justinechacko.in/). Please suggest correct code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;

$('.navbar-nav > li > a[href="/' + pathname.replace(/\//g,'') + '"]').addClass('active');
```